# Difference between <action method="append"> and <block...><block ... /></block>

Tags: layout, blocks

My current understanding of defining layout blocks is that if I do:

```
<block type="core/template" name="a.b" as="aB" template="some.phtml">
    <block type="x/y" name="c.d" as="cD" />
</block>
```

then I've added `c.d` as a child block of `a.b`, and from within `some.phtml` I can call `$this->getChildHtml('cD');` to ask `c.d` to render its output at that position in the template.

I was looking around in `catalog.xml`, and I've just come across the syntax:

```
<action method="append"><block>block.name</block></action>
```

so I followed it to see what's different from the previous method:

```
public function append($block, $alias = '')
{
    $this->insert($block, '', true, $alias);
    return $this;
}

....

public function insert($block, $siblingName = '', $after = false, $alias = '')
```

`append` implies ordering the child block at the end of the parent block, but I could have easily done that with an `after="-"` parameter in the first method.

So, what's the difference between these two methods of adding a child block to a parent block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`append` appends an existing block that is referenced by name, to a new parent. It can be used to move a block to another location or to duplicate it.

`<block>` always creates a new block.

Comment: So <block> creates a new instance, while append simply manipulates an existing instance?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. Correct.